# How can I get the previous URL in PHP?

Tags: php, hyperlink, external

I want to check with PHP if a webpage from my website is opened by clicking directly from a link within my website or from an external link.

I have found a solution with JS but I want it to be coded with PHP

Thanks for all your suggestions in advance :)